# select option gets stuck on the first option not being able to read in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple select, with 2 input options

```
<select class="form-control seta-select input-layout max-width-none-i width-100-i" id="campo-relatorio" name="Relatorio" style="background-color: #00000060" onchange="ContaMasterFiltraRelatorio()">
                                            <option value="Detalhado" selected>Detalhado</option>
                                            <option value="Consolidado">Consolidado</option>
                                        </select>
```

The problem occurs in `javascript`, whenever I select any of the options it is always as if I had selected the “Detalhado”

```
function ContaMasterFiltraRelatorio() {
    var campo = document.querySelector("#campo-relatorio");
    if (campo.value == "Detalhado") {
        (...)
    }
    else if (campo.value == "Consolidado") {
        (...)
    }
}
```

When I inspect the code at execution it is always found in the first if of the `javascript` it always accuses the 1st case, how can I solve it?

Comment: The example works perfectly fine for me. Have you included a [mre]?

Comment: Looks ok. Please create a [mre]. See: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992)

Comment: You have `selected` set in the option.  Why would you expect it to be anything else but the selected option?  `<option value="Detalhado" **selected**>Detalhado</option>`

Comment: I found out what the problem was, somewhere else in the project there was a variable with the same id, so it never changed, I changed the id and it solved it